# Changing the loading message for SAML SSO in WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 Identity Server 4.0.0 SAML SSO functionality and would like to change "Loading WSO2 Stratoslive..." message to something else (translate it to other language in my case). Where is this message located and how could i change it?

I already tried to replace the message in "redirect_ajaxprocessor.jsp" located in org.wso2.carbon.sso.redirector.ui_2.0.1.jar and "redirect_ajaxprocessor.jsp" located in org.wso2.stratos.identity.saml2.sso.mgt.ui_2.0.1.jar but no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nop. you don't have to change sso-mgt, just sso.redirector.ui_2.0.1.jar and "redirect_ajaxprocessor.jsp" is enough